# How to use getRange to select non-adjacent rows?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to copy ranges "A1", "C1:Z1", "A3", "C3:Z3", "A6", "C6:Z6" from source sheet and paste the values of those cells to the "target" sheet while eliminating the non-selected cells (such as column "B", row2, row4 and 5.

Source
[image]

Target
[image]

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getRange()` to retrieve all  of the range and exclude col2, row 2, 4 and 5 using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
const values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
const rowIndexToArrayIndex = num => num - 1;
const excludeCols = [2].map(rowIndexToArrayIndex);
const excludeRows = [2, 4, 5].map(rowIndexToArrayIndex);
const filteredValues = values
  .filter((_row, i) => !excludeRows.includes(i))
  .map(row => row.filter((_, j) => !excludeCols.includes(j)));
console.info({ values, filteredValues });
```

```js
//MOCK values
const sourceSheet = {
  getDataRange: () => ({
    getValues: () =>
      [...new Array(5)].map(
        (i => () => new Array(10).fill().map(() => ++i))(0)
      ),
  }),
};
//MOCK ends 

const values = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
const rowIndexToArrayIndex = num => num - 1;
const excludeCols = [2].map(rowIndexToArrayIndex);
const excludeRows = [2, 4, 5].map(rowIndexToArrayIndex);
const filteredValues = values
  .filter((_row, i) => !excludeRows.includes(i))
  .map(row => row.filter((_, j) => !excludeCols.includes(j)));
console.info({ values, filteredValues });
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the values of cells with the highlighted background color from the source sheet to the target sheet using Google Apps Script.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve the background colors and values from the source sheet.
2. Create an array for copying to the target sheet using the retrieved background colors and values.
3. Put the created array to the target sheet.

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample, from your sample input and output iamges, the values of the cells with highlighted background color are retrieved. Before you use this script, please set the variables of `sourceSheetName, destinationSheetName, backgroundColor`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceSheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the source sheet name.
  var destinationSheetName = "Sheet2";  // Please set the destination sheet name.
  var backgroundColor = "###";  // Please set the background color you want to check.
  
  // 1. Retrieve the background colors and values from the source sheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var range = srcSheet.getDataRange();
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // 2. Create an array for copying to the target sheet using the retrieved background colors and values.
  var copyValues = backgroundColors.reduce((ar1, r, i) => {
    var temp = r.reduce((ar2, c, j) => {
      if (c == backgroundColor) ar2.push(values[i][j]);
      return ar2;
    }, []);
    if (temp.length > 0) ar1.push(temp);
    return ar1;
  }, []);
  
  //  3. Put the created array to the target sheet.
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, copyValues.length, copyValues[0].length).setValues(copyValues);
}
```

#### Sample script 2:

In this pattern, in your sample input situation, for example, even when the cells "C3" and "A6" are the default background color, the script copies the values from the highlighted cells by removing the columns with the default background color.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceSheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the source sheet name.
  var destinationSheetName = "Sheet2";  // Please set the destination sheet name.
  var backgroundColor = "###";  // Please set the background color you want to check.
  
  // 1. Retrieve the background colors and values from the source sheet.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var range = srcSheet.getDataRange();
  var backgroundColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  // 2. Create an array for copying to the target sheet using the retrieved background colors and values.
  var tempValues = backgroundColors.reduce((ar1, r, i) => {
    var temp = r.reduce((ar2, c, j) => {
      ar2[j] = c == backgroundColor ? values[i][j] : "";
      return ar2;
    }, []);
    if (temp.length > 0 && temp.some(e => e.toString() != "")) {
      ar1.push(temp);
    }
    return ar1;
  }, []);
  var obj = tempValues.reduce((o, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c.toString() == "" && i == 0) o[j] = true;
      if (c.toString() != "" && o[j] && i > 0) delete o[j];
    });
    return o;
  }, {});
  var copyValues = tempValues.map(r => r.filter((_, j) => !obj[j]));
  
  //  3. Put the created array to the target sheet.
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, copyValues.length, copyValues[0].length).setValues(copyValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- In your sample script, I prepared from your input situation. So when your actual situation is different from the sample situation, the script might not work. So please be careful this.
- If you want to copy the values of cells except for the default background color `#ffffff`, please modify above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      if (c == backgroundColor) ar2.push(values[i][j]);
    ```
  - To:

    ```
      if (c != "#ffffff") ar2.push(values[i][j]);
    ```
  - or
  - From

    ```
      ar2[j] = c == backgroundColor ? values[i][j] : "";
    ```
  - To:

    ```
      ar2[j] = c != "#ffffff" ? values[i][j] : "";
    ```
- When the Spreadsheet of the source sheet and the taget sheet is different, please modify `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.

#### References:

- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed elaboration! The highlights were simply for the demonstration purposes to make it easy to spot which cells I intended to transfer over: sorry for not making it clear in the original post. Your solutions and explanations however are very creative and easy to digest! I'm certain there are definitely occasions where your methods will come in handy later down in the road. Thanks again!

Comment: @Shan Jiang Thank you for replying. I apologize I misunderstood your question. From your replying, I could notice it. But also from your replying, if my sample will be useful for users, I'm glad. So I would like to leave my answer.